# Undismiss dependabot allert on Github repo

Tags: github, dependabot

I was a bit hasty with conclusions and dismissed one alert that I should not have. I can't find anything in the UI, nor in the articles about Dependabot nor in the Github API that would allow me to revert that action.

Is it possible? Can this be reverted? Or maybe it's a feature being worked on and can ship someday?

Answer (score 0):

It seems GitHub was updated, and now has a "reopen" button for the dismissed issues

[image: GitHub now has reopen button]